# How to manage libraries in deployment

Tags: python, ruby, linux, deployment

I run [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com) on Mac OS X. I am coding inside a virtual machine with [CentOS 6](https://www.centos.org), and I have the same versions of Python and Ruby in my development and production environment. I have these restrictions:

1. I cannot manually install. Everything must come through RPM.
2. I cannot use `pip install` and `gem install` to install the libraries I want as the system is managed through [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com), and everything I add will be removed.
3. `yum` has old packages. I usually cannot find the latest versions of the libraries.

I would like to put my libraries locally in a `lib` directory near my scripts, and create an RPM that includes those frozen versions of dependencies. I cannot find an easy way to bundle my libraries for my scripts and push everything into my production server. I would like to know the easiest way to gather my dependencies in Python and Ruby.

I tried:

- `virtualenv` (with `--relocatable` option)
- `PYTHONPATH`
- `sys.path.append("lib path")`

I don't know which is the right way to go. Also for ruby, is there any way to solve my problems with [bundler](http://bundler.io)? I see that bundler is for rails. Does it work for custom small scripts?

I like the approach in [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org) and [NPM](https://www.npmjs.org); all packages are stored locally in `node_modules`. I have nodejs rpm installed, and I deploy a folder with my application on the production server. I would like to do it this way in Ruby and Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Node, but what you describe for NPM seems to be exactly what a virtualenv is. Once the virtualenv is activated, pip installs only within that virtualenv - so puppet won't interfere. You can write out your current list of packages to a requirements.txt file with `pip freeze`, and recreate the whole thing again with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Ideally you would then deploy with puppet, and the deploy step would involve creating or updating the virtualenv, activating it, then running that pip command.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at Docker?

With Docker you could create a image of your specific environment and deploy that.

https://www.docker.com/whatisdocker/